# Unity Augmented Reality House Animation Moving up through the image target?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I wanted to make house animation to move up through the image target 
like this link
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aE8vGmhL7Fs&t=121s&list=LLBNWw5L9PQCZS-SZCdAukqg&index=31

with this script

```
public class HouseAnimation : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator Anim;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Anim.GetComponent<Animator>();
        Anim.speed = 0f;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void AnimUp()
    {
        Anim.Play("HouseAnim", -1, 0f);
        Anim.speed = 1f;
    }
}
```

but this script as the link video for a button click .

I want implement this script without a button click, so i tried to edit the  DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs for that

DefaultTrackableEventHandler

```
public class DefaultTrackableEventHandler : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler
{
    private Animator Anim;

 protected virtual void Start()

    {

        Anim.GetComponent<Animator>();
        Anim.speed = 0f;

        mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();

        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
            mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);


    }

  protected virtual void OnTrackingFound()
    {

        Anim.Play("HouseAnim", -1, 0f);
        Anim.speed = 1f;
}
```

it only works if i chech the Loop check box for the animation..but i just want it to appear once i image target detected.

Please help me to edit it correctly??